# Explanation - a logon event with logon type 5 comes after logoff event with logon type 10

Tags: authentication, events, server, event-handling, logout

I am reviewing event viewer. A user account session was terminated after a admin user logins to the server. EventViewer shows that a logoff event was triggered with logon type 10 (Remote terminal login) before a logon event with logon type 5 (service startup). Admin user connected to the server via RDP. Can anyone explain why the user login session was terminated when this admin user login? There was no prompt to kick out the login user and the server allows multiple sessions

A server that allows multiple session shouldnt terminate an existing user session. However, in this case it does. Reviewed event viewer and found the information above